# IE 11 won't execute php file

Tags: php, internet-explorer

In fact, i have a website who works perfectly on Chrome, Opera or Firefox, and almost perfectly on IE 11, the fact is that index.php works, paramsoc.php works BUT param.php won't works it just say  `"Would you like to open or record param.php from localhost ? "`

i try to make a `header('Content-Type: text/html');` but no change...

But i can't find where it came from... 
Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of param.php? Are you placing your header before all output?

Comment: it's quite a long page...756 rows :/ and yes the header is in first place...

Comment: Well, can you post any snippets? Or outline the general structure of your file. How does it start? How does it end? Where is the HTML?

Comment: Have you looked in your browsers traffic inspector to see what response headers are actually being sent?

Comment: Oh right, i didn't think about that. So i got the error HTML1527 and i don't understand here is the beginning of param.php http://pastebin.com/tDKdWeR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i find why it was not functionning, it was the   `<?php require_once('traitement/requete.php');   ?>` who was too close from the html tag. I just move it lower on the file and replace the require_once by a require and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open that file from directory directly then you can get that problem.

Try to open it from local server.

Comment: i try from localhost/[myproject]/param.php